# In what sense is GCD an extension of boolean OR?

Tags: lo.logic, boolean-algebras

The J Programming langauge has an operator which acts as [both the GCD and boolean Or](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d101.htm).  The [J Primer](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/primer/vocabulary.htm) has this note about it:

> The GCD is a useful extension of the domain of the or function to non-boolean arguments.

As J is a highly mathematical language, I assume this extension has a basis in mathematics as well.

In what sense, if any, can the the GCD be considered an "extension" of boolean "Or"?

Comment: Boundary cases of the gcd function are usually (but not always) defined like gcd$(0,0)=0$ and gcd$(0,1)=1$.  And of course gcd$(1,1)=1$.  So if boolean is mapped to integer as F=0,T=1, gcd agrees with OR.

Comment: GCD is the meet (max) of the exponents of primes, and meet, union, OR are synonymous in lattice theory.

Comment: @FanZheng Are you making a separate point or a point related to the one Bjorn makes in his answer?

Answer (score 18):

In the ordering $\preceq$ of nonnegative integers by divisibility, 1 is the least element and 0 is the greatest, and we have for instance
$$
1\preceq 2\preceq 6\preceq 12\preceq\dots\preceq 0.$$
In this ordering, gcd is the same as meet (*greatest lower bound*), which is dual to *least upper bound*, which is what boolean OR is for $\{0,1\}$.

So it makes sense if you think of numbers as "degrees of truth", where **multiplicative factors** are evidence of falsehood.

See also: [What is gcd(0,0)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495119/what-is-gcd0-0)

Comment: Great answer.  Is the idea of degrees of truth and factors as evidence of falsehood used in any formal theory you know of -- perhaps fuzzy logic or something related?

Comment: @Jonah I kind of doubt anyone would use it that way except as an example

Comment: @Jonah : Forcing in set theory employs partially ordered sets whose elements could be thought of as "degrees of truth" but I am not aware of applications of forcing that use the partial ordering of nonnegative integers by divisibility.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything deeper here than that J gives gcd the same values as OR when the arguments are 0 or 1. That is all it says on the web page you link to.  It just means that J computes gcd$(1,1)=1$, gcd$(0,1)=1$ and gcd$(0,0)=0$. Only the last one is not standard (gcd$(0,0)$ is often considered as undefined).

Comment: Do you know why gcd(0,0) is often considered as undefined?

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen : I think it is because if you read the phrase "greatest common divisor" literally, then there is no such thing as the greatest common divisor of 0 and 0 since every positive integer divides 0.

Comment: @TimothyChow ah yes, that's it.